# kendo-dropdownlist for vue, How to set default value

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I am using an array of objects to populate a vue kendo dropdownlist control.

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist
    :data-source="months"
    :data-text-field="'abbrev'"
    :data-value-field="'value'"
    v-model="internal.selectedMonth"
  ></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

My array looks like this:

```
 months: [
        {
          text: "January",
          abbrev:"Jan",
          value: 1,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "February",
          abbrev:"Feb",
          value: 2,
          numDays: 28
        },
        {
          text: "March",
          abbrev:"Mar",
          value: 3,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "April",
          abbrev:"Apr",
          value: 4,
          numDays: 30
        },
        {
          text: "May",
          abbrev:"May",
          value: 5,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "June",
          abbrev:"Jun",
          value: 6,
          numDays: 30
        },
        {
          text: "July",
          abbrev:"Jul",
          value: 7,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "August",
          abbrev:"Aug",
          value: 8,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "September",
          abbrev:"Sep",
          value: 9,
          numDays: 30
        },
        {
          text: "October",
          abbrev:"Oct",
          value: 10,
          numDays: 31
        },
        {
          text: "November",
          abbrev:"Nov",
          value: 11,
          numDays: 30
        },
        {
          text: "December",
          abbrev:"Dec",
          value: 12,
          numDays: 31
        }
      ]
```

When the page loads my model is set to null but the value "January" is selected in the control. Vue developer tool shows that the model has not been set so the UI is out of sync with the model.

How do I get it to show nothing until the user selects an actual value (or the model is loaded elsewhere)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an empty option in the start of the array with value null

`{
    text: "",
    abbrev:"",
    value: null, 
    numDays: null 
}`